# Fingerprint Support - Ubuntu

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader, ubuntu-drivers

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 - Model# PF-1j8ptz laptop and have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have having issues when trying to get the fingerprint to work. I have gone through and tested many options from different posts with no luck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Output of `sudo lsusb | grep -i finger`

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc. Metallica MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
```

Comment: Fingerprint readers are really hit and miss with driver support. Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `sudo lsusb`? This will show the hardware ID of the fingerprint reader, making it possible to check for compatibility 

Comment: Thanks Matigo - I have edited and added in the output requested

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get this working following this link.
https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity